# How to find the position of a company given other companies in a Pandas DataFrame with Python

Tags: python, pandas, visualization, market-basket-analysis

So I have a `Pandas DataFrame`. I am doing some `data analysis` with `Python` with some sets of companies based on the products they offer on my website.

For example, I have a column called `ProductID` and another called `Company`

So to find the most trending products on my website, I can do so by:

```
df.ProductID.value_counts(normalize=True).nlargest(10).plot(kind="bar")
```

And each product is offered by a `company`, and a company could have several products, that is a company can have several `ProductID`. ie `Company A` has `ProductID` 10,12,13,14

How do I find the market position of a company? Keeping in mind that out of the top 10, a company's product could appear up to 3 times or even more depending on the company's popularity

Comment: By market position, what exactly do you mean by this?